# What is the correct return value of the BCM_SETSHIELD Windows API message?

Tags: c++, winapi, cbutton

What is the correct return value of the BCM_SETSHIELD message?

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcm-setshield states that it returns 1 on success and an error code otherwise, but in my tests it seems to return 0 when successfully setting the shield.

The documentation for the Button_SetElevationRequiredState macro states it returns void, but the actual implementation returns LRESULT.

The documentation for the MFC CButton (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class?view=msvc-170) states that there is a method CButton::SetElevationRequired that returns BOOL.

But there is no such method. Instead there is a method CButton::SetShield that returns a HICON.

Comment: Probably documentation errors. If `BCM_SETSHIELD` did in fact return an error code on failure, and you're getting 0, then that would be `ERROR_SUCCESS`. Sounds like this message always returns an error code (0 meaning success). The `Button_SetElevationRequiredState` macro documentation is clearly bogus (like all other function-like macros). They are **all** documented to return `void`. Just ignore. `CButton::SetElevationRequired` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#setelevationrequired) but not in any header or source files.

Comment: When they moved to learn.microsoft.com and github they broke the return value for all macros during migration. It is probably in comctl6 so it should not be hard to debug. Fake a icon load failure...

Comment: You can submit the feedback in the documentation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcwXh.png

Answer (score 0):

After more research it turns out that the most correct is the MFC implementation.

BCM_SETSHIELD returns the icon handle of the previous image (if any), similar to what BM_SETIMAGE does.

So, on first call it most likely will return NULL, and on subsequent calls for the same button it will return a handle.

There seems no possibility of an error value being returned.